# Appendchild based on data-attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, appendchild

I've got a few divs like this:

```
<div id="thisisme" data-order="1">
<div id="thisisme" data-order="2">
```

I want to add some content to the specific div with data-order = 1. The Javascript-code:

```
var hello = document.getElementById('thisisme');
thisisme.textContent = "blabla"; 
hello.appendChild(thisisme);
```

This will add it to both divs. But I only want to add the content to div number 1. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of `id` should be unique in the `DOM` so you need to fix that.

Maybe switch to using `class` that will work.

Then use `css` selector syntax.

```js
const hello = document.querySelector('.thisisme[data-order="1"]');
hello.innerText = "blabla";
```

```html
<div class="thisisme" data-order="1">1</div>
<div class="thisisme" data-order="2">2</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your help! Actually turning everything to a class fixed the problem I had with an earlier code I wrote but didn't work. I'm moving forward in my project, but I keep your answer in mind, since it's probably better then the one I've got now working :)